# How can I get an Edge animation to stop looping with scroll effect?

Tags: animation, scroll, html5-canvas, adobe-edge, muse

I am trying to get an adobe edge animation to animate as I scroll and then stop animating when it reaches the end of the animation, but continue scrolling. I am using adobe muse and placing my .oam file and then adding the edge animate scroll effect to advance 1 second every 20px. The problem is that it is looping the animation when I want it to stop. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like the only way to accomplish this right now is to either hide the element and replace it with a static one as soon as the animation is done in Muse, or extend the length of the animation after it is done animating in Edge Animate like 40 seconds and hope that your site never scrolls further than that. Dana Cooper from adobe stated, "We may be working on having the option to stop the animation at some point in the future, but for now there is only the option to have the animation replay." https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1338176